# Meteor basic routing not working and its basic but not working

Tags: meteor

As I understood from documentnaton these are the steps to create a routes buts its not working

My meteor Version is : Meteor 1.0.1

also

root@localhost basic]# meteor add iron:router
      added iron:location at version 1.0.4
      added iron:dynamic-template at version 1.0.5
      added iron:router at version 1.0.5
      added iron:layout at version 1.0.5
      added iron:middleware-stack at version 1.0.4
      added iron:url at version 1.0.4
      added iron:controller at version 1.0.4
      added iron:core at version 1.0.4

Tried sample app with below code but always its showing the blank page with out anything

```
My code as follows 
this is basic.js

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('hi', {
    path: '/hi',"enter code here"
    template: 'hello'
  });
});

# this is basic.html

<head>
  <title>Meteor Routing Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> yield}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</template>

Can you please guide me if i am doing something wrong enter code here. I am opening this in http://locahost:3000 and http://locahost:3000/hi but not at all working
```

Comment: You're using the old Iron Router API with `Router.map`. Try using the new API as specified in [the official Iron Router guide](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md).

Comment: Also, could you point out the source of the documentation you're reading? The Meteor docs (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/) don't explain how to use Iron Router because it's not part of the Meteor core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First as sbking said, you can use the more recent Route definition from iron:router for your routing like :

in your basic.js

```
//definition of the route
Router.route('/hi', function () { //Here the path
  this.render('hello');     // Here the name of the template you want to render
});
```

You have no route for '/' so you will see nothing at `http://localhost:3000/`
But if you go to `http://locahost:3000/hi` normally you will see your Hello world

But go read the iron:router guide ! It is worth it !